# RadioButton already selected

Tags: java, android

I'm using a `RadioGroup` in my layout.
When I run the program, I'm getting the first RadioButton already selected out of 4 RadioButtons.
I want none of these RadioButtons initially selected.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem , might want to post some code snippet.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to set non of your `RadioButton` to selected by default than use 
**`android:checked="false"`** in your `RadioButton`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/choiceOne"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="choiceOne" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/choiceTwo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="choiceTwo" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/choiceThree"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="choiceThree" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/choiceFour"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="choiceFour" />

    </RadioGroup>
```

**EDIT**

if you want to set default radio button to selected than there is two way

1. You can use **`android:checked="true"`** in particular `RadioButton`
2. You can use [**`android:checkedButton="@+id/choiceOne"`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#attr_android:checkedButton) in your `RadioGroup`

   > The id of the child radio button that should be checked by default within this radio group.

**SAMPLE CODE FOR OPTION TWO**

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:checkedButton="@+id/choiceOne"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/choiceOne"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="choiceOne" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/choiceTwo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="choiceTwo" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/choiceThree"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="choiceThree" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/choiceFour"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="choiceFour" />

    </RadioGroup>
```